# apache.commons.logging classNotFound even after added dependency to Maven

Tags: java, maven, javafx

### General info

I am using VSCode on Windows 10 PC. My project is a desktop app that use JDK 11 + javaFX 11 + Maven. I had the same issue with intelli J.
this is the repository: https://github.com/Osolemio44/Appiculture.git
branch: `fix/modulenotfound`

### Issue

Getting this error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory. Can someone help me on fix this?

Full log:

```
Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplicationWithArgs(LauncherImpl.java:464)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication(LauncherImpl.java:363)        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)        
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at java.base/sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper.main(LauncherHelper.java:1051)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application start method
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:900)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/logging/LogFactory
        at jasperreports@6.17.0/net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.<clinit>(JasperFillManager.java:81)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.OperationManager.printApiaryReport(OperationManager.java:186)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.views.MainController.refreshWebview(MainController.java:827)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.views.MainController$1.changed(MainController.java:176)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.views.MainController$1.changed(MainController.java:1)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleChange.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:181)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectPropertyBase.java:74)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyObjectWrapper.java:102)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.markInvalid(ObjectPropertyBase.java:113)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ObjectPropertyBase.set(ObjectPropertyBase.java:147)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedItem(SelectionModel.java:105)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.lambda$new$0(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:67)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper$SingleInvalidation.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:136)
        at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.binding.ExpressionHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ExpressionHelper.java:80)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerPropertyBase.java:72)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.fireValueChangedEvent(ReadOnlyIntegerWrapper.java:102)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.markInvalid(IntegerPropertyBase.java:114)
        at javafx.base/javafx.beans.property.IntegerPropertyBase.set(IntegerPropertyBase.java:148)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.SelectionModel.setSelectedIndex(SelectionModel.java:69)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:412)
        at javafx.controls/javafx.scene.control.MultipleSelectionModelBase.select(MultipleSelectionModelBase.java:444)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.views.MainController.initialApiaryConfig(MainController.java:145)
        at Appiculture/com.base.controllers.views.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:103)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2573)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2466)
        at javafx.fxml/javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2435)
        at Appiculture/com.base.Launcher.start(Launcher.java:33)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$9(LauncherImpl.java:846)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$12(PlatformImpl.java:455)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:428)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$11(PlatformImpl.java:427)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
        at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:174)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:581)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:522)
        ... 37 more
Exception running application com.base.Launcher
```

### Solutions i tried

I have read several stack overflow posts and none have worked for me. Here is what I have tried:

1. Clean and rebuild project
2. Adding the following dependency in my POM:

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

3. add compile to the commns-logging dependency.
4. updating jasperreport dependency to a newer version.

### pom.xml file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.base</groupId>
    <artifactId>Appiculture</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1</version>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.34.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.sf.jasperreports/jasperreports -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
            <version>6.17.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--        javaFX-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-web</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-media</artifactId>
            <version>11.0.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.base.Launcher</mainClass>
                    <executable>C:\libs\jdk-11\bin\jlink</executable>
                </configuration>
            </plugin> -->
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>11</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>11</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>


</project>
```

Comment: VsCode is not an IDE my friend. It is a code editor with a couple of powerful extensions. Try using another IDE that takes care of a lot of things for you, such as Eclipse, NetBeans or IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: when you install all the plugins, VSCode act like and IDE, and it's a very good solution. I also tried IntelliJ and had the same issue. Anyway, that's not the point.

Comment: You can check in your `.m2` folder if the `apache.commons.logging` dependency is available, if not the try to do maven sync in your VSCode. there may be a plugin available for that task.

Comment: yes, the dependency is present in the .m2 folder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the project has conflicting transitive dependencies. Also, the error appeared intermittently. That was because the loading time is variable and sometimes it loads the correct dependency and sometimes it doesn't.
The solution was to add this Maven plugin that is responsible for always loading the most recent dependency:

https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions

Remember to always do a Maven Clean.